# How to fix items in div class="row" angular + bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Do anyone have idea how to fix elements in div with `class="row"` ?

**How it should look like:** [Good view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXw6.png), **Click**: [Live show](http://symbiot4.creatingo.com/lights.html)(example without angular)

**How it looks like:** [Bad view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Gua.png)

Switch component is repeated in lights component
When i remove `<div class="row"></div>` elements looking good, but the [are under themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TbBi.png)

```html
<div class="row">
    <app-switch  *ngFor="let switch of switches" [switch]="switch"></app-switch>
</div>
```

Link to my repository: [SmartPi-Client](https://github.com/marcin1mn/SmartPi-Client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding **.col-sm-12 .col-md-6 .col-xl-4** to child div of app-switch, add it to app-switch.

```
<div class="row">
    <app-switch class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let switch of switches" [switch]="switch"></app-switch>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because Bootstrap 4 is using Flexbox. `app-switch` selector is between `.row` and `.col` divs so the correct bootstrap style wasn't applied to them.
You can make the browser to ignore this `app-switch` selector using the following css code.

```
:host {
  display: contents;
}
```

I added a working example here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ho3q4q

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the style for the columns is applied to the direct child/ren of the html element with the ‚row‘ class.

You could add that class to your app-switch component tag or use a wrapper around it to define the col design